# cin.get(); doesn't work when I put it in a if statement

Tags: c++

I used cin.get() to get the program to pause and wait for user input, and it works fine. The moment I put it in an if statement, it just skips that "wait" period and continues on with the code? How can I solve this. Here is the section that is not working.

```
  do
    {
        cout << "\n\n\nEnter the number of one of the following and I will explain!\n";
        cout << "1.integer  2.boolian   3.floats   4.doubles   5.character";
        cout << "\n\n[when you are done type 'done' to continue]\n\n";
        cin >> option;

        if (option = 1);
        {
            cout << "\nInteger is the variable abbreviated as 'int' this allows C++ to only";
            cout << "\nreadwhole and real numbers \n\n";
            cin.get(); //this is the part where it just skips.. it should wait
        }

    } while (var = 1);
```

Comment: As @0x499602D2 is pointing out in comments on my answer, you have a bunch of other problems. Make sure you read those comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin >> option` will extract whatever integer is in the input stream but will leave the following newline character (which is there from hitting enter after typing in the value). When you do `cin.get()` it is simply extracting that newline character which is already there. Like so many other questions like this, the solution is to empty the input stream after you've extracted into `option`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You are also using assignment (`=`) where you should be comparing for equality (`==`).

Comment: +1 Also the `while (var = 1)` and `if (option = 1);`. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks, hadn't noticed. Added it to my answer.

Comment: No problem. But he also has a semicolon in `if (option = 1);`